# Is there any explanation for dowsing?

Tags: electromagnetism

A friend of mine told me about this "method" called dowsing used to find underground water so they can make a well and he told me it has something to do with electromagnetism. I honestly don't believe him, but I did some research about it and I found no paper or article about this, just a bunch of webpages I don't trust. Can anyone tell me why does this work or doesn't and why? In case it doesn't, why do all the people I've talked with about this tell me it does work? Is it coincidence or something like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no basis in physics for dowsing. It's like reading tea leaves in a cup to predict the future. The practitioner has other means to make guesses and uses the action of swirling the tea or holding the forked stick, or the bent coat hanger wires, to 1) impress the audience and 2) focus their own attention upon watching for cues and clues upon which to formulate their guesses.

Professional water dowsers are usually well drillers too, and over time they learn where the water table is close to the surface, based on the number of wells they have already drilled in the vicinity. The bit with the stick or the wires is then for show.

Comment: I agree there is no known basis in physics, but it is certainly not "like reading tea leaves". My late grandfather was regularly called on by the local farmers to find the location of blockages in drains (to save wasted effort digging in the wrong place) and wouldn't have got regular payments year after year unless he was accurate. But he didn't claim any knowledge of *how* dowsing worked. In his view people could either do it, or they couldn't. I saw him doing it (successfully) many times, but my personal "success rate" was precisely zero.

Comment: I could predict the location of the water main leading into a house with a pair of bent coat hanger wires only if I knew in advance the location of the water meter at the curb and the sink or toilet closest to it inside the house. But that's because in my mind, I drew a straight line between the meter and the closest sink and when I stepped over that line on the front lawn I was "dowsing", the coat hanger wires would swing in. This was in 1965, when I was 13, and my audience was easily impressed.